# How choose record using filter?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I use selenium webdriver. I have such code  - `driver.findElement(By.name("ctsk")).sendKeys("1234");`. It plus some other similar command filled in new record. After I need find this record in overview. So I use such code - `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='columnTitle2']/input")).sendKeys("1234");`. But if I use such command once again it doesn't rewrite value in filter but add new value to previous value. For example instead "1234" I get  "12341234". How can I set new value, not just add?

Comment: By calling `sendKeys` you are simply passing more input. You should set the value on the element instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way is to [clear](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#clear%28%29) WebElements before you enter more data...